# how to upload files in django backend?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to create an upload file function in my website. However , i keep getting the error
`The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form`. I tried to create a `post` function in `views.py`. Does this mean any files that i uploaded is not considered a file ?

`models.py`

```
class ClinicVisit(models.Model):
    upload_attachment = models.FileField(null=True , blank=True, upload_to='uploads/')
```

`views.py`

```
class ClinicVisitList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClinicVisitSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = ClinicVisitFilter
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
    ordering = ['-created_at']
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ClinicVisit.objects.based_on_access_level(self.request.user)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_serializer = ClinicVisitSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.data)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return response.Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return response.Response(file_serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class ClinicVisitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
    upload_attachment = serializers.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = ClinicVisit
        exclude = clinicvisit_exclude
        extra_kwargs = {
            "staff_relationship": {"required": True},
            "visit_type": {"required": True},
            "visit_status": {"required": True},
        }
```

Comment: Your `<form>` tag must have `enctype=multipart/form-data`, which is not the default enctype.  Are doing that in your template?

Comment: my frontend is using vuejs and nuxt. I passing data based on vue router. this is the code for my vuetify frontend component for file input `<v-file-input
           v-if= "isFileInput(input.type)"
           label="Attachment"
           v-model="inputs[i].value"
           :outlined="outlined"
           >`

Comment: If you do View Source in your browser, you should be able to see what kind of `<input>` tag it generated.

Comment: `<div>class="v-file-input__text"</div>` is this the input you are referring?

Comment: Ah, so it's handled in Javascript.  There's no way to know without digging into the code.